# Better way to normalize these tables?

Tags: mysql, database-design

This is more of a backend design question.  I'd be using the following 3 tables to populate dropdowns in a web app.

```
CREATE TABLE request_types(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name as varchar(32) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE citizenship_types(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name as varchar(32) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE designation_types(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name as varchar(32) NOT NULL
);
```

The design of all 3 is identical, so I'm wondering if it would be a better practice to do something like the following with data of all 3 tables put into a single one and using another to differentiate what group the values belong to.

```
CREATE TABLE field_types(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name as varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    category TINYINT NOT NULL
)


CREATE TABLE category_types(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name as varchar(32) NOT NULL
)
```

where category_types would be populated like so:

```
{
    1:"request",
    2:"citizenship",
    3:"designation"
}
```

Comment: This would only be useful if other tables have columns that can be a foreign key to any of the types. You lose the ability to specify that a column can only contain a citizenship ID.

Comment: Stick with what you've got, and set name as UNIQUE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually *not* normalized. You can't name any rule of database normalization that would lead you to this design.

One of the normalization rules is that an attribute column must depend *only* on the key of the table, not on another attribute column. In your design, the `name` attribute depends in part on the non-key column `category`.

I suggest reading a book like [SQL and Relational Theory](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/sql-and-relational/9781491941164/).

Comment: I stuck with the first choice. But just for the sake of argument, what about using id and category as a composite primary key?

Comment: I think you're trying to use an antipattern called the [One True Lookup Table](http://www.dbazine.com/ofinterest/oi-articles/celko22/). It's an old, old mistake.